# How to take Cassandra backup weekly?

Tags: cassandra, database-backups

How to take cassandra keyspace backup(snapshot) weekly by using nodetool? I mean how to take snapshot of only latest 1 week data.?

Answer (score 2):

The way nodetool takes a snapshot of a keyspace is by creating a hard link to the SSTables.  This means it is innately a full backup every time.  You can enable incremental backups in Cassandra which will do a backup each time Cassandra flushes a memtable to an SStable.  I don't believe there is a way to take a snapshot of JUST the last week of data in Cassandra using Nodetool.

Linking just in case you haven't seen the Datastax documentation around Snapshots and Incremental Backups.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html

Comment: I haven seen the Datastax documentation around Snapshots and Incremental Backups. I also agreed that there is no option like weekly back up. But I need to take backup weekly once. Is there any other way that takes weekly backups other than writing queries?

Comment: Why would taking another snapshot a week after the first not accommodate what you need?  Because of storage constraints?  Just wondering.  Besides that I don't know of a way to do a "weekly" backup.  Hopefully someone else can chime in with a solution if that doesn't work.